# Local Notification on ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, notifications, local

I have the following code in `ViewController.m`:

```
-(void) checker {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [notification setAlertBody: @"Im your local notification"];
    [notification setFireDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 1]];
    [notification setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [UIApplication setScheduledLocalNotifications: [NSArray arrayWithObject: notification]];
}
```

The last line produces a warning:

> Class method '+setScheduledLocalNotifications' not found (return type defaults to id)

and it gives error while processing. How can I instantiate the notification? As I said I am new, if you can provide a complete answer it will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I have a timer that repeats itself every 60 seconds and calls a function that puts a notification.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(checker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

/* ... */
-(void)checker {
    NSLog(@"Notification routine");
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.(if needed)
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    // Create a new notification.
    UILocalNotification* alarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (alarm) {
        alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.alertBody = @"Msg to show";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
}
```

I can see the log only firing once a minute, but the `oldNotifications` count does not increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it,

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

// Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.(if needed)
if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
    [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

// Create a new notification.
UILocalNotification* alarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
if (alarm)
{
    alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60];//afterone hour
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
    alarm.alertBody = @"Msg to show";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
}
```

update:

```
- (void)scheduleAlarmForDate:(NSDate*)theDate andBody:(NSString*)Body
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    // Create a new notification.
    UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];//Using ARC no autorelease
    if (alarm)
    {
        alarm.fireDate = theDate;
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
        alarm.alertBody = Body;
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
}
```

now if I call this method twice,

```
 NSDate *fireDate1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:4.0];
[self scheduleAlarmForDate:fireDate1 andBody:@"My alertBody 1"];

NSDate *fireDate2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:6.0];
[self scheduleAlarmForDate:fireDate2 andBody:@"My alertBody 2"];
```

the first alarm will be canceled,,

Comment: Aziz:  I basically copied and pasted your example. The notification works great!!!  but the clearing of the notification is not  (they are stacking )  Dont know what im doing wrong here.

Comment: I've tested it, it clears all old notifications, it's weird thats not happening with you,, make sure your not calling it twice somewhere else,,

Comment: The only change I made is that I shortened the time to 10 seconds, so my statement looks like this "alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];"

Comment: what is your ios version and are you using 3GS, there where a bug on the 3GS.

Comment: My simulator is running 6.1 (10B141)

Comment: Aziz:   I changed it to the way its on your edited version, and it only shows one message....I am very curious as the difference.

Comment: Aziz:  One more comment....I removed the 2nd notification (My alertBody 2) and the notifications do not clear anymore....now I am seriously curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Aziz   I believe that the array was preventing it from clearing old nofications (havent research it, but it might be 0 based, so the first notification only makes it - 0)   Thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

the '+' in the error message means it is trying to call a class method rather than an instance method. The `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` call will return the singleton instance of the application object that allows you to call that method as an instance method.

Also you should read the documentation  for [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You just need to call `scheduleLocalNotification:` with the notification object to get it scheduled. This will allow you to release the memory to the object, because the schedule method will copy the object.